# Artifacts compatibility while upgrading Spark 3.1.2 to Spark 3.4.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, upgrade

Currently, we are using spark 3.1.2 with Java 1.8.0 and Scala 2.12 but we need to upgrade it to spark 3.4.0. We are using below JARs, package and artifacts with Spark 3.1.2:
**JARs:**

- postgresql-42.2.12.jar
- ojdbc6.jar
- hive-warehouse-connector-assembly-1.0.0.3.1.0.0-78.jar
- postgresql-42.2.12.jar
- hadoop-aws-3.2.0.jar
- aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.375.jar

**Packages:**

- org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.1.2
- io.delta:delta-core_2.12:1.0.0
- org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.1_2.12:0.13.1
- io.minio:minio:8.0.0

So I was curious to know, how can I get to know compatibility of each one.

Comment: This is the compatibility matrix for delta-core package https://docs.delta.io/latest/releases.html#compatibility-with-apache-spark

Comment: Also `iceberg-spark-runtime` has a version per spark release https://iceberg.apache.org/releases/